# Android: Loop sound file in oncreate

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I want to loop my sound mp3 file in `onCreate()` method infinitely.

My code in onCreate method is as follows :

```
  mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound_7);
  mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
  Log.e("beep","started1");
  mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
          mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound_7);
          mMediaPlayer.start();
      }
  });
  mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
  Log.d("beep","started0");
  mMediaPlayer.start();
```

But this code plays my audio file only once. Please help !!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't do this in onCreate, but in onResume. Stop the sound in onPause!

Comment: @RvdK - Thanks! i did it in onResume but how to remember my sound preference(on/off) when i navigate to next screen and back to the same screen? It always plays it infinitely, even if i stop it before leaving the screen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
void playMp3()
{

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound_7);
    mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
            Log.e("beep","started1");
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    playMp3();
                }
         });
    Log.d("beep","started0");
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

And If your sound file is small then `SoundPool` instead of `MediaPlayer`

```
private void initializeSoundPool(){
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                        int status) {
                    loaded = true;
                    playFile();
                    initializeSoundPool();
                }
            });
            soundID = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.glassbreak, 1);        
        }
```

call this methode

```
private void playFile(){
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
         float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                 .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
         float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                 .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
         float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
         if (loaded) {
             mSoundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
             Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
         }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between initializeSoundPool() and playFile() method. Which is better approach for small file.

Comment: what is soundID here ?